# GetTokenInformation with TokenGroups

Tags: c++, windows, security, winapi

Why does GetTokenInformation with TokenGroups return much longer list of user groups than

```
net user <username>
```

command or those that are listed in "Local Users and Groups"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the groups (Interactive, Logon SID, Authenticated Users etc) are volatile, they are added by the system when the user logs in and are only part of a token object (logon session). APIs/tools for administration of user accounts generally don't deal with tokens (Only logged in users have a token) but focus on things that are part of the user account database (SAM and/or active directory)

Comment: Whereas "logged in" only means that there is a process running as that user, right? What I mean is that the distinction of interactive logon and the API view of it should be made clearer.

Comment: Logged in means logging in on the welcome screen/remote desktop OR some process calling LogonUser(). (There does not have to be a process)

Comment: Okay, fair point. Strictly speaking there doesn't have to be a process (or thread), because that is mostly what comes afterward.